# How to install the libnl3-*-dev(el) packages from your distro

Tags: networking, command-line, package-management, 19.10

I'm trying to configure the Microcheckpointing feature for providing fault tolerance to VMs in the Ubuntu system 19.10.

While going through the steps I came across this error.

```
   ERROR:  NetLink v3 libs/headers not present.
        Please install the libnl3-*-dev(el) packages from your distro.
```

What does this mean and how do I install this? I tried installing the `libnl-3-dev` package but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try: `sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev`

Comment: @singrium yes that's what i did.

Comment: Try also installing `libnl-route-3-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `apt search` first:

```
❯ apt search "libnl-3"
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libnl-3-200/focal,now 3.4.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  library for dealing with netlink sockets

libnl-3-200-dbg/focal 3.4.0-1 amd64
  debug symbols for libnl3

libnl-3-dev/focal 3.4.0-1 amd64
  development library and headers for libnl-3
```

Then installed using:

```
sudo apt install libnl-3-dev
```